# How to addClass to a body tag inside a generated iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, colorbox

I'm using JQ Colorbox plug-in (a sort of Lightbox) and I'd like to add a class to the body of a document loaded via Colorbox's iframe function.

Basically, I was trying to:

```
$("iframe").contents().find('body').addClass('foo');
```

but that doesn't seem to work, probably because my iframes are not generated until after a user invoke Colorbox?

Is there a way to achieve such result?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [ColorBox documentation](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) says that there are 4 event hooks you can use. For example (lifted from their examples page);

```
$("#myColorBox").colorbox({
    onComplete: function(){
        alert('onComplete: colorbox has displayed the loaded content');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried your code and it works, but this one triggers an error: http://pastebin.com/asxUNe3x that says that $ is undefined. I think I'm missing something.

Comment: $ is jQuery. Make sure jQuery had loaded before you call $.